# Is there a way to tally in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have data of the following form

```
ID
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
```

How can I tally? So the result would be

```
n count
1  2
2  0
3  2
```

in SQL Server

Edit: Sorry, I misspoke. Notice that n != ID. n is the number of distincs (1), doubles (2), triples (3). So this is different from previous questions that that I want to group by count not by ID.

Comment: `select id, count(*) from the_table group by id`?

Comment: tally is the word that got you distracted, you should have searched for how to `Count` a value's occurrence in sql server

Answer (score 1):

yes, try this:

```
SELECT id, count(id)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY id
```